# EF6 - Code First - Point to Another Database

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have an existing C# Project that is working fine with an existing database using EF6 - Code First. 
I changed my web.config to point to a newer copy of my Database that was copied manually by my DBA that works fine too.

Problem - 
I now want to create a new table in the new database(newer copy of my Database). 
I create my Model Class as usual and add them to my Context Class. 
But now my update-database command shows to create **all the tables, indexes etc.** in the newer database.

Is there a way to skip this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to apply code first migration in a existing database, you need to apply a empty migration. You need to flow below step for applying code first migration in existing database:-

1. Revert your code to the point before you started modifying.
2. Generate a migration.
3. Remove everything in the Up method (for applying empty migration)
4. Apply the migration with update-database
5. Re-apply the changes you made.
6. Generate another migration
7. Apply the migration.